# Why getting "The input type is invalid" when accessing edit.php?

Tags: errors

I have setup a wordpress blog at domain.com/blog using nginx. I can see all the wordpress pages and access the admin dashboard, and various admin pages. But, when I try to access 'edit.php', I am getting an error message displayed in the browser -

```
The input type is invalid
```

So, I turned the debug on and found in the logs -

```
Undefined offset: 1 in /home/projects/webapps/blog/wp-includes/vars.php on line 31
```

My nginx setup is -

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  www.domain.com domain.com 22.22.22.22;

root /home/projects/webapps;

location /blog {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args; 
}

location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$; 
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;  
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you always had this issue? Are you running any plugins that are related to the Pages menu?

Comment: No, just recently. The only active plugin is Yoast SEO.

Comment: an undefined offset shouldn't cause that issue, my guess is with your nginx config. something with the query string is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm not sure this will fix your issue, but your error in your log (especially the file where it is called from) tells me it's a query vars issue likely from a bad regex or a bad routing of the request in your nginx config.

replace your line

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
```

with

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

and replace (this one I'm not sure it's required, but you could try it too)

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
```

with

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$request_filename;
```